# How to properly read out data from the firebase using Angularfire and async and Observables?

Tags: angular, firebase, async-await, observable, angularfire

I'm trying to read out data from Firebase where in a simple query I'm retrieving organization by the provided name.

The challenge I'm facing is that the query works fine and data gets retrieved but in the execution flow the logic where the actual data is read out kicks in too late.

I think it relates to how I handle Observables but I'm really stuck.

Here is my code:

```
async getOneOrganizationByName(name: string) {
        console.log("2. Doing the check");
        const query = this.afs.collection<Organization>('organizations', ref => ref.where('name', '==', name).limit(1));

        return query.snapshotChanges().pipe(
            debounceTime(500),
            take(1),
            map(
                changes => { 
                    return changes.map(a => {
                        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Organization;
                        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
                        console.log("3. From the check logic: " + data.name);   
                        return data;
                    });
                }
            )
        );
    }

    async nameExists(name: string) {
        if(_.isNil(name)) {
            return false;
        }
        console.log("1. Before the check");

        let foundName: string;

        (await this.getOneOrganizationByName(name)).subscribe((organizations: Organization[]) => {
            foundName = organizations[0].subdomain;
            console.log("4. Set item: " + organizations[0].subdomain);
        });

        console.log("5. Found item: " + foundName);

        if(_.isNil(foundName)) {
            console.log("6. return false")
            return false;
        }
        console.log("6. return true")
        return true
    }
```

From the code above I would expect to see in the console output: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 with respective messages, yet I get 1, 2, 5, 6, **3, 4**.

How can I assure blocking of the execution of the logic till the data is read out?

Comment: Put the code in subscribe callback.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
        console.log("5. Found item: " + foundName);

        if(_.isNil(foundName)) {
            console.log("6. return false")
            return false;
        }
 console.log("6. return true")
```

Needs to be inside the `subscribe` callback. Since `Observables` are used in asychronous code, therefore when you retrieve data, the code after the `subscribe` will be called **first**, and when the data is retrieved fully then the code inside the `subscribe` will be called.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed worked well. One more follow up question... How do I invoke the "nameExists" method from the component in a sync way? I have the following `console.log("Before");
this.myService.nameExists(name);
console.log("After");` and I would like to have output `Before,1,2,3,4,5,6,After` yet I get `Before,After,1,2,3,4,5,6`